# Better to use useState or set as constants in functional component (React Native application)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I have a constant userIndex in my React Native application that uses functional components.

I initialize userIndex using the following:

```
const [userIndex, setUserIndex] = useState(0);
```

I also have a constant called renderedUserIndex. To me, there seems to be two ways to set this constant:

```
OPTION A:
const renderedUserIndex = userIndex % 2 === 0 ? userIndex : userIndex + 1;
```

The second is:

```
OPTION B:
const [renderedUserIndex, setRenderedUserIndex] = useState(0);

useState(() => {
   setRenderedUserIndex(userIndex % 2 === 0 ? userIndex : userIndex + 1); 
}, [userIndex]);
```

Which method is preferred?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you meant to `useEffect` in the last snippet and answer the question like that.

Option A is definitely the way to go. If you are using the `renderedUserIndex` in the same functional component then there is really no reason to save it in its own state.

Option B could be used if you need the two indexes to diverge at some point but otherwise, it will not be needed.

Comment: Hey @Yann You are absolutely right that Option A is correct but with option A there is one small flaw that It will unnecessary calculate the renderUserIndex with every render irrespective of the change in value of userIndex so to prevent it we need to use useMemo hook like I defined in below answer.

Comment: I agree with you in principle but I think that the overhead of checking against equality and storing the old value is about the same as just recalculating it. After all, it's just a modulo.

Comment: Yes there is always a tradeoff between time and space complexity but it's not about how small a operation is performed It's about that a operation is performed with every render but it's not needed and you never know how many time render method fires so in react it always better to memoize all the operations which can be memoized.
so conclusion is it's depends on the component if you are sure that component is small and render will not be fired many times then you can skip memoize but if you are not sure always use it.
As it's good to be rain checked :)

Answer (score 1):

The best appraoch would be follow

```
const renderUserIndex = useMemo(() => userIndex % 2 === 0 ? userIndex : userIndex + 1 , [userIndex])
```

As now renderUserIndex will only be calculated when userIndex changes mean s It will not be calculated unnecessarily with every render.